# how to call a jquery function from a c# application?

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to call a jquery function from a C# application. I have an idea how to do that as already did some research on it. But Im stuck on how to start with it.

I added `System.Web.UI` in the references, but can only find `ClientScriptManager`, I dont see a `ScriptManager`, nor do I see a `ClientScript` as mentioned in some forums. So I began with this:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jQuery", jsText, false);
```

but seemed like I need to get an object of `ClientScriptManager` to do this. So I created an object of `ClientScriptManager`:

```
ClientScriptManager csm = new ClientScriptManager();
```

now I get an error saying `ClientScriptManager does not have a constructor`.

Any help on how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He wants to decide at server side whether or not to run a client script.  This is quite normal.

Comment: @Archer yeah, I mesread the question. I though he was trying to run a specific jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

Use Page.ClientScript instead...

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "jQuery", jsText, false);
```

Comment: That fixed the error. Thanks!

However code doesnt seem to be calling the js function. I'm actually trying to use imagelens.js to magnify a custom made browser.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Are you adding `<script></script>` tags to jsText?  If not, change the last parameter to true.  Otherwise, check where the script is in the page to make sure it's after you include imagelens.js.  Finally, if no luck with that, show us a bit more code so we can see if that helps.  Also, are you getting any errors in the browser console window?

Comment: Where should I put imagelens.js? I have just added it to the project. Nope it compiles and runs smooth. Im actually writing out to the Console, if it gets in that area of code. and it does.

Comment: here's a code snippet: 
`(string jsText = "<script src=\"jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script><script src=\"jquery.imageLens.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>$(\"thisBrowser\").imageLens();";
                        System.Console.WriteLine("magnify: arr.Count=" + arr.Count());
csm = pg.ClientScript;                        this.csm.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jQuery", jsText, false);`
thisBrowser is my browser object which needs to be magnified.

Comment: You need script tags around the code you want to run...  `string jsText = "<script src=\"jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script><script src=\"jquery.imageLens.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">$(\"thisBrowser\").imageLens();</script>";`

Comment: Also, is thisBrowser the class or ID?  It needs to be prefixed with . or #

Comment: I prefixed thisBrowser with #.

Comment: I prefixed thisBrowser with #.
still its not working. Im assuming Im using the wrong way to send the object to the function...
Can you provide me with a very simple jQuery function, something like a 'Hello World' to test if the jQuery gets called or not? Thanks!

Comment: Did you wrap the call to imageLens in script tags as I showed above?

Comment: All I can suggest is that you look in the browser console, not the console in VS, and see if there are any errors.  What you have there is correct.  Incidentally, as you said above that this is answered you should accept the answer and ask any new queries as a new question.